# Filter dropdown choices based on another fields value: [Django, django-smart-selects]

Tags: django, django-models, django-smart-selects

I want to show only relevant option in `first_model_field` dropdown based on values of `product` and `product_state`. When admin changes values of one of these fields in `SecondModel`, it should get only `first_model_field` choices that have same state and product. How can I get filtered `FirstModel` based on these two values without writing async JavaScript ? It should also change when one of these values changes in dropdown.

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_state = models.CharField(default=PRODUCT_STATE_START, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES)

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_state = models.CharField(default=PRODUCT_STATE_START, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES)
    first_model_field = ChainedForeignKey(
        FirstModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        chained_field="product",
        chained_model_field="product",
    )
```

*ps: Currently it only filters based on product field*

Comment: You can chain product status based on product selection & then chain `first_model_field`